# secure underlaying directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have created an axtra ftp account for someone else, so he can upload files.(tournament results, about 20/30 htm files and images)
I am also very paranoid, so in case he upload "possible dangerous" files, i do not want those files to be accessible via an http request. With the help of PHP I want to grab the content of those files. (I do not expect troubles with that yet)

Problem: 
My hoster does not allow extra ftp accounts have access outside the public_html. 
So i thought htacces should solve my problem. Just by deny from all rule.
But with ftp acces this htaccess file can be deleted or changed.

So i tried to add the following code in my main htacces file in the root of my site:

```
<Directory "/home/xxxx.nl/public_html/xxxxxxxx.nl/onzetoernooien/swissmaster_ftp">
deny from all
</Directory>
```

My site hung with an internal server error.
I have no access to the httpd file.

My idea was to use an htacces file above this directory.
If the absolute path was incorrect, i could use some kind of wildcard, like *swissmaster?

I have searched on the Apache website, but i get lost in the overwhelming amount of information.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use a `<Directory>` section in .htaccess, only in the server configuration file. That causes the server error (check your error logs and you'll see the error message). We can't secure a subdirectory with a `<Filesmatch "subdir/.*$">` either, as FilesMatch examines only the filename part of the requested URI.

You can, however, use mod_rewrite, along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^subdir.*$ - [NC,F]
```

If the requested URI matches the regex pattern `subdir.*` (so "subdir" followed by anything else; you may need to tweak the pattern, as it happily catches subdir_new/something.txt too -- I'm sure you get the idea), then mod_rewrite's [F flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) will return a 403 Forbidden status (the NC stands for No-Case, making the pattern case-insensitive).

Comment: I did add that rewrite rule and my site did not went down, but the directory is still accessible. So i think i have to play with the expression itself. I have replaced subdir by swissmaster_ftp.

Comment: Yesssssssssssssssssssssss! The ^ sign means the beginning of a string, so when left out it works! Now i have to watch out for duplicate names, else that won't be accessible too. Thank you Sat!

Comment: I'm glad it worked :). For the expression I'd suggest `^full/path/to/subdir(/.*)?` -- either nothing (to take care of the index), or a slash and zero or more characters (index, all files and nested directories). I think that'd cover every problem.